# Share custom object related to Opportunity with Opportunity Team

Tags: sharing, sharing-rule, apex-managed-sharing, opportunity-teams

I have a question surronding sharing of related records with Opportunity teams.

We have an custom object A related to the Opportunity object. Opportunities are Public, while Object A is private.

Is it possible to share records of Object A which are related to the Opportunity with the account team only? Or would this require manual sharing / Apex sharing?

I've looked into the sharing rules but there are no options for sharing with "Team". And since the opportunity teams could be comprised of a wide assortment of roles, using that for the rule doesn't seem to be doable..

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do it apex sharing.
Either by apex code or you can use Flow that will generate the sharing (depend on the complexity).

Comment: That was what i feared - Thanks for your reply :)